# How to create redundant array of assorted commodity hard drives?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, lvm

Well, I have some good old hard drives and a good idea is to combine them into an array.

For example:

- `250G`
- `300G`
- `500G`
- `1000G`
- `2000G`

(There is also a 3000G drive, but I'll save it for regular backups).

What I want: a cheap Linux programmatic way to combine them with some redundancy (of course, I'm willing to lose 50% of the space).

This would be the perfect solution if minimal human power consumption is needed: I want to just add devices to the pool and choose K-security up to 2 or maybe up to 3 (so that each block is stored on at least 3 disks). It would be even better if the thing has fault tolerance and can reallocate blocks if one of the disks fails.

Yeah, like HDFS or Vertica, but for mere mortals :)

Of course, this will be a very cheap solution without ECC and HW RAID.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think btrfs should work for you